# Add an entire directory (recusively) of php/js/css scripts to fapolicyd

Tags: rhel8

RHEL's `fapolicyd` docs show how to [whitelist](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening) a specific application, but is there a way to whitelist an entire directory structure of files consisting of php, js, css and pdf types?

Using `fapolicyd` in debug mode:

```
# fapolicyd --debug-deny 2> fapolicy.output &
```

My denial output looks like:

> rule=11 dec=deny_audit perm=open auid=1000 pid=3005001
> exe=/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server :
> path=/data/www/nbsprod/public_html/fax.php ftype=text/x-php trust=0

This occurs when one of our developers attempts to upload an existing file to the www directory.

If I set `fapolicyd` to permissive, the file is uploaded no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is considered best practice but I fixed this by

Add new rule:

```
# fapolicyd-cli --file add /data/www/nbsprod/public_html/ --trust-file nbsprod_pub_html
```

Update rules with `fapolicyd-cli`

```
# fapolicyd-cli --update
```

Verify that `fapolicyd` is set to run in enforcing mode (not permissive)

```
# vi /etc/fapolicyd/fapolicyd.conf

...
permissive = 0
...
```

Restart `fapolicyd`

```
# fapolicyd-cli --update
```

End user now able to upload scripts to the www directory specified above with `fapolicyd` running in deny mode.